# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Hr#internal_employee_page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am learner ruby on rails,I want to join two model(tables).
User.rb(users table)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base has_many :offer_letters end
```

OfferLetter.rb(offer_letter table)

```
class OfferLetter < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :user end
```

HrController(hr_controller.rb)

```
class HrController < ApplicationController
    def internal_employee_page
        @employees = OfferLetter.joins(:user).where(:id => :candidate_id)       
end
```

end

when run my code I got error "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'offer_letters.user_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `offer_letters`.* FROM `offer_letters` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `offer_letters`.`user_id` WHERE `offer_letters`.`id` = NULL"

```
<div id="job_details">
    <% @employees.each do |emp| %>
       <%= render partial: "hr/employee_details", locals: {emp: emp} %>
    <% end %>               
</div>
```

Error in this line : <% @employees.each do |emp| %>
So tell me where i am wrong

Comment: when we use joins, we have to specify table name(should be plural ) with its attribute. So in your where clause please specify id with its respective table like for ex: OfferLetter.joins(:user).where(users.id => :candidate_id)

Answer (score 0):

when we use joins, we have to specify table name(should be plural ) with its attribute. So in your where clause please specify id with its respective table like for ex:

```
@employees = OfferLetter.joins(:user).where('users.id = ?', candidate_id)
```

OR

```
@employees = OfferLetter.joins(:user).where('offer_letters.id = ?', candidate_id)
```

Comment: Hi Navin, I tried this @employees = OfferLetter.joins(:user).where('users.id = ?', candidate_id). But i got error  "The Error is *****Association named 'user' was not found on OfferLetter; perhaps you misspelled it?***** at same place

Comment: After this error, I also tried put association rules in OfferLetter model belongs_to :user  and in User model has_one :offer_letter then I got the following error "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'offer_letters.user_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `offer_letters`.* FROM `offer_letters` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `offer_letters`.`user_id` WHERE (users.id = 14)"

Comment: here I thing "users.id = offer_letters.user_id" instead of "users.id = offer_letthers.candidate_id" because users.id equals to offer_letters.candidate_id

Comment: No, The error is "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'offer_letters.user_id' in 'on clause': SELECT offer_letters.* FROM offer_letters INNER JOIN users ON users.id = offer_letters.user_id WHERE (users.id = 14)"

Comment: try it with singular version of user not users. replace users.id with user.id